# Bootstrap is overriding

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this problem with a website I'm building. I'm trying to implement php code to connect to some external search engine but I found myself having some problems I can't fix. I realised somehow my bootstrap is overriding with the one from the server I want to implement it so it doesn't allow my web to find my style.css. I don't know if I'm making any sense. If anyone could have a look would be super great.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://lostonyouagency.com/css/bootstrap.min.css?8656">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://lostonyouagency.com/style.css?6959">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://lostonyouagency.com/css/animate.min.css?2803">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://lostonyouagency.com/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://lostonyouagency.com/css/ionicons.min.css">
```

Here are some pictures of my issue:

[image: example]

If I remove `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://lostonyouagency.com/css/bootstrap.min.css?8656">` all the external widgets will work but then I will face some serious problems on my menu bar. I don't know what else to do, I have tried quite a few things! Someone told me I need to edit the Css class but I don't know how to do it!

Also chrome is telling me it can find the assets/css/style.css.map

Comment: Chrome 404 map is fine. Regarding styles how are you linking the css files in your page. Your CSS file should be linked only after Bootstrap, otherwise bootstrap may over ride your style rules.

Comment: Hi @kiranvj thanks for answering! But the other Css files are after bootstrap! Is that what you mean or there is something else I need to do?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. Do you have a link to the website which I can see. Without seeing a working version, I am unable to say what is the issue.

Comment: Here is the link: https://www.volfly.net but there is a php code inside.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have 2 version of Bootstrap in your page. Bootstrap 4 and bootstrap 3.x

[image]

The first highlighted CSS has Bootstrap version 4. Second highlight has Bootstrap 3x inside it along with other styles.

This looks like a conflict between both versions and your styles.

Comment: The second bootstrap is from merlinx the company who gave me the php code to implement on my page. I through they were using a older version of bootstrap but what to do to fix it?

Comment: Can I see what exactly is breaking?

Comment: Yes! If you look on safari. The search engine doesn't work good and the box under. The menu bar is also afected and the footer.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/mGaNTbx.png https://i.imgur.com/bo1cDsd.png https://i.imgur.com/WvTyELH.png https://i.imgur.com/4H2dERf.png

Comment: Did you have a change to have a log to the pictures?

Comment: Unable to check, my proxy is blocking imgur.com also I dont have Safari, so not sure if can find a fix. You can post a new question, mentioning you have multiple Bootstrap versions with breakage screen shot, you might get more helpful info.